# Borrar variables en url de la mejor manera!

Tags: php, jquery

Que otras alternativas tengo además de headerremove para limpiar el url de mi documento al cargar /recargar una página y obtener variables en casos especiales por get? 
Me gusta la idea de enviar variables por url en el backend y limpiarlas de la misma manera después de obtenerlas, 
Desconozco si es una buena práctica!

Answer (score 1):

En `PHP` podrías hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
session_start();

if ( !empty( $_GET ) ) {

   // En el caso que este NO este vacío el $_GET
   // lo pasamos a una variable de sesión
   // y limpiamos la URL sin los parametros $_GET con el header(..)

   $_SESSION[ 'variable_get' ] = $_GET;
   header('Location: http://ejemplo.com');
}

if ( !empty( $_SESSION[ 'variable_get' ] ) ) {

   // En el caso que este vacío el $_GET 
   // y NO este vacío la variable de sesión variable_get
   // lo pasamos de vuelta a la variable $_GET
   // y reseteamos la variable de sesión variable_get

   $_GET = $_SESSION[ 'variable_get' ];
   $_SESSION[ 'variable_get' ] = null;
}
else {
   // Tratar error de no haber obtenido nada
   // header(..);
   // exit;
}    

// A partir de aquí puedes usar la variable $_GET con la URL limpia
```

Comment: Excelente!! En este ejemplo crees que funcionaría igual, si no creo variable de sesión? Mas bien crear una variable global! Seguiría su valor en el background incluso si actualizó la página no?

Comment: @matteo - No eso se perdería.. deberías usar la variable global de `$_SESSION` para que tengas los datos al actualizar la página

Answer (score 1):

No es una buena practica, ya que al hacer esto la "navegacion y experiencia de usuario, asi como su historial" queda afectado.

¿Porque?, esto se debe a que muchas personas utilizan los botones "adelante y atras" del navegador y cuando tu recargas, al dar "atras" vuelve a cargar la misma pagina que va con tus variables get y tu script vuelve a recargar el sitio.

Esto hace que el usuario "Quede atrapado" en la misma pagina, sin mencionar que tu servidor debe servir 1 vez mas el sitio, que incrementa la carga sobre el mismo y quizás guardar las variables en sesión, que incrementa tu uso de memoria.

Recomiendo en ese caso, enviar tus variables por POST para que esten ocultas y las personas no puedan verlas en tu url.

Las variables GET estan destinadas a navegación y a "petición de informacion" 
por ello se nombran "get".

Una vez, vi un sitio donde tenian un iframe general, con todo el sitio incrustado. Esto hacia que el url que el usuario observaba, era www.-urldelsitio-.com y todo lo demas, se manejaba en el iframe por lo que las variables get siempre estaban ocultas.

Esa es una de muchas formas de ocultar tus url, pero vuelvo al punto anterior. Creo que buena aplicacion, no oculta sus url, incluso pueden ser amigables ya que estan destinadas para la navegación.

Suerte amigo.

Comment: Gracias por el aporte!